# How to properly convert string form post variables to objects or arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have tried most of the solutions I found, but cannot get it to work.

I have a form parameter that post list of ids separated with commas in a string as per

```
$list_of_ids = "261,420,788";
```

Now I need to convert the list of ids into object or arrays so that I can loop through it and insert into database.

My problem is how I can make it look like this:

```
["261","420","788"]
```

Here is how I will like to loop it and update database

```
foreach($list as $id){

echo $id;
// loop and update database


}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why. Are you wanting to store and later use comma-separated values?

Comment: You can explode it then use for update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use explode :

```
$string= "123,234,345";
$array = explode(",",$string);
```

Output :

> Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => 234 [2] => 345 )

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = explode(",", $list_of_ids);
```

Should give you an array of the numbers. Take precaution against sql-injections though, if you want to put this into a database!

Comment: Thanks alot. Esp for reminding me of Sql Injections. I just upvoted